# netrw `Ex` sometimes creates a split

Tags: netrw

I'm usually in 2 vertical splits, in each one I jump in an out of files using `:Ex`. When a split shows a file and I type `:Ex` I expect this split to show me the netrw UI, where I can choose another file.

But sometimes instead of replacing the split, `:Ex` will create a horizontal split inside this split and show me both the netrw UI and the file I was previously viewing. I haven't identified when and how, was wondering if you could help me understand if I'm using it wrong.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is directly explained under [`:help :Explore`](https://vimhelp.org/pi_netrw.txt.html#netrw-%3AExplore):

> `:Explore` will open the local-directory browser on the current file's directory (or on directory `[dir]` if specified). **The window will be split only if the file has been modified and `'hidden'` is not set**, otherwise the browsing window will take over that window.  Normally the splitting is taken horizontally.

You might want to consider adding `set hidden` to your vimrc to ensure `:Explore` will not create a new split. See [`:help 'hidden'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27hidden%27) for details. I generally recommend enabling this option, I think it's quite useful behavior and it's not really counterintuitive, it doesn't take much to get used to its behavior.

---

As a general advice, when you have questions about a specific command or setting or behavior in Vim, start looking at `:help` (+ whatever command you're running.) Vim's help system is *very* good and in the vast majority of cases will have very direct answers to the questions you might have.